# Unexpected EOF Syntax Error in GraphiQL with FastAPI and Strawberry GraphQL

Tags: graphql, fastapi, graphiql, strawberry-graphql

I'm experimenting with a [FastAPI app GraphQL](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/graphql/) and some made up fake data for learning purposes:

```
import strawberry
from fastapi import FastAPI
from strawberry.asgi import GraphQL
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame with temperature readings for three zones
data = {'Zone1_Temp': [20, 21, 19], 'Zone2_Temp': [22, 23, 21], 'Zone3_Temp': [24, 25, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field
    def average_zone_temp(self) -> float:
        return df.mean().mean()

    @strawberry.field
    def coldest_zone_temp(self) -> str:
        coldest_temp = df.min().min()
        coldest_zone = df.idxmin()[df.min() == coldest_temp].index[0]
        return f"{coldest_zone} with {coldest_temp} degrees C"

    @strawberry.field
    def warmest_zone_temp(self) -> str:
        warmest_temp = df.max().max()
        warmest_zone = df.idxmax()[df.max() == warmest_temp].index[0]
        return f"{warmest_zone} with {warmest_temp} degrees C"

schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query)

graphql_app = GraphQL(schema)

app = FastAPI()
app.add_route("/graphql", graphql_app)
```

which appears to work fine when using a Python script to retrieve that query of made up data:

```
import requests
import json

# Endpoint URL
url = 'http://192.168.0.102:8000/graphql'

def make_graphql_query(query: str):
    # Headers
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    # Make the POST request
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={'query': query})

    # Parse and return the response
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)
    else:
        return f"Query failed with status code {response.status_code}. Query: {query}"

# Separate queries for average, coldest, and warmest temperatures
query_avg = '{ averageZoneTemp }'
query_coldest = '{ coldestZoneTemp }'
query_warmest = '{ warmestZoneTemp }'

print("Average Temperature:")
print(make_graphql_query(query_avg))

print("\nColdest Temperature:")
print(make_graphql_query(query_coldest))

print("\nWarmest Temperature:")
print(make_graphql_query(query_warmest))
```

This will print back:

```
Average Temperature:
{
    "data": {
        "averageZoneTemp": 22.0
    }
}

Coldest Temperature:
{
    "data": {
        "coldestZoneTemp": "Zone1_Temp with 19 degrees C"
    }
}

Warmest Temperature:
{
    "data": {
        "warmestZoneTemp": "Zone3_Temp with 25 degrees C"
    }
}
```

BUT this FastAPI app also appears to have a browser tool which I am having issues with:
[image]

It seems like no matter what I try in this `Variable` and `Header` section I either get an invalid JSON Error message or even this when I run it with nothing:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 31,
          "column": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Not a lot of wisdom here at all so any tips appreciated... Am stumped why the python script works but the `Graphi` tool does not.